# Grid and calendar per week scripting

Tags: php, calendar, grid

I'm very new to PHP so I wanted to ask how to start coding something like a weekly calendar that will display appointment status and to be specific something similar to this site ->> http://www.barberbart.com/week.php

any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats gonna take a lot or work.

You want to read up on and get extremely familiar with looping and the time and date functions.